# How to get Azure Blob file size

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I used Azure blob to store images. Users upload those images. I want to see how much space each user occupy with their images. How can I do that in ASP.NET code behind? Can I get an image file size just by knowing its URI? Or do I need use some blob related function?

Answer (score 67):

You need to fetch a blob's properties first. Eg,

```
var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
if (blob.Exists())
{
    blob.FetchAttributes();
    return blob.Properties.Length;
}

throw new Exception("Blob doesn't exist");
```

Answer (score 8):

As Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob is deprectated and sould be replaced with Azure.Storage.Blobs there is a new way to do it, you still need to get the blob's properties, then the property is now named `ContentLength`:

```
BlobClient blob = myBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
if (blob != null){
     var properties = (await blob.GetPropertiesAsync()).Value;
     Console.WriteLine($" {blob.Name}\t{properties.ContentLength}");
}
```

Comment: `BlobProperties.ContentLength` returns the downloadable length/size of the blob as-seen from a client, it isn't the same thing as the amount of storage-space a blob uses in its container, which would factor-in snapshots, unique/nonunique pages, uncommited blocks, etc - so calculating total storage space used is nontrivial, see this official PowerShell script for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-billing-size-powershell#sample-script

Answer (score 6):

Answering for scala/java here, in case someone is stuck. In order to get the size of the blob you can make use of the following code:

```
val blob: CloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobPath)
blob.downloadAttributes()
blob.getProperties.getLength
```

Make sure you definitely call downloadAttributes else the properties will be empty.

You can refer to this documentation for more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-java-legacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContentLength` property of `BlobDownloadInfo`, which is returned by `BlobClient.DownloadAsync()` (or `Download()`).

Comment: does this mean the file has to be downloaded first before getting size?

Comment: Yes, ContentLength contains proper value only for downloaded blobs.