# How to get file size from Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have a subfolder in Azure named productimages.Inside productimages folder I have lots of images now I want to fetch the image URL and also the file size. I have abled to fetch URLs but could not fetch the file sizes. Another thing when I fetch the URL from blob it does not come in order for instance instead of coming as 1.jpg, 2.jpg it comes like 9999.jpg .... 1.jpg.

MY CODE:

```
public List<ProductDataVM> RetrieveFileInfoFromBlob()
        {
            List<ProductDataVM> plists = new List<ProductDataVM>();
            var files = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "productimages/", useFlatBlobListing: true);
            var cnt = files.Count();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {

                ProductDataVM ob = new ProductDataVM();
                ob.ImageUrl = file.Uri.ToString();
                ob.FileSize = file.Properties.Length; // in this line it gives IListBlobItem' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'
                plists.Add(ob);
            }

            return plists;

        }
```

**Your kind help will be higly appreciated.**

Comment: I think you're just missing file.FetchAttributes(); before calling file.Properties.Length;

Comment: @JohnD Thanks for your kind reply but did not find anything like file.FetchAttributes() just tried .

Comment: you might want to check similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281492/how-to-get-azure-blob-file-size

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to `CloudBlob` and using `file.FetchAttributes()` first:

```
public List<ProductDataVM> RetrieveFileInfoFromBlob()
        {
            List<ProductDataVM> plists = new List<ProductDataVM>();
            var files = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "productimages/", useFlatBlobListing: true);
            var cnt = files.Count();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var blobFile = (CloudBlob)file;
                ProductDataVM ob = new ProductDataVM();
                ob.ImageUrl = blobFile.Uri.ToString();
                blobFile.FetchAttributes();
                ob.FileSize = blobFile.Properties.Length; // in this line it gives IListBlobItem' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'
                plists.Add(ob);
            }

            return plists;

        }
```

Comment: thanks mate its working but filesize is returning as 24330 instead of 23.7 kb . is there any way to save value as kb

Comment: Divide it by 1000

Comment: Thanks, @anon but could you please tell me in order to get URLs by order from the blob what can I do as the URLs is not coming in order but I need URLs in order as I will have to store it at the db table.

Comment: @Mahmud, divide 24330 by 1024 to get 23.75 which is in Kb