# Get report of file sizes from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to access the blob storage and get file sizes and file paths report. I need to download that report. My file sotrage structure inside the blob storage is there are four named folders. Then for each user there is a auto generated GUID folder. Inside the folder there are the files. I need to get a list of file sizes and file path (or file name). Whats the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could get files with `prefix`, and get file size with `ContentLength`(Size in bytes) using [GetBlobsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsasync?view=azure-dotnet).

For example, you will get all files in directoryA when setting prefix as "directoryA". Storage URL looks like `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/directoryA/filename`.

```
private static async Task ListBlobsFlatListing(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient,
                                        int? segmentSize, string yourPrefix)
{
    try
    {
        // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
        var resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: yourPrefix)
            .AsPages(default, segmentSize);

        // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
        await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blob name: {0}", blobItem.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Blob content length: {0}", blobItem.Properties.ContentLength);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

You can use this method to convert the ContentLength you got to MB:

```
static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}
```

And the above is based on storage v12. If using the older version(v11), you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27710325/13308381).